# CSS3 specifications on w3.org

Tags: css

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-roadmap/

Hasn't CSS3 been out since a while now? Why is most of the specification not complete?

Is there a complete reference anywhere on the web (or in a book)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS 2.1 was finalized only a couple of years ago. As Hogan said, this could take 10 years. CSS3 was introduced just a few years ago itself. Standards are based on implementation, not invention.

Comment: It (CSS2.1) is still only a "draft" :-) Of course "draft" for a W3C spec is *roughly* the same as "theory" in a scientific context: "completed" being the equivalent of a "law". +1 for pointing out that W3C (as opposed to some other "standards" organizations) is heavily influenced by implementations.

Comment: @pst - You're right. I don't know why I thought I had read it was finalized.

Answer (score 1):

This work takes time, a lot to be done.

Check "CSS3 for Web Designers"
http://books.alistapart.com/products/css3-for-web-designers

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a nicely compiled [list of CSS3 specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_3).

Answer (score 0):

Does this link help: http://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_CSS

Standards are a slow process -- you can see newer stuff in that list.  A book is probably your best bet to see a "distilled" version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a presentation I wrote showing [the state of the union in HTML5](http://www.slideshare.net/senchainc/html5-state-of-the-union) (and satellite specs) and CSS3. The CSS3 section is in the middle.

CSS3 basics are there, but there are many advanced features that have not been implemented yet, and IE is particularly laggard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct CSS3 has advanced features it is not been in use as much it has o be i would like to enhance the face the web by utilising those features of CSS3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it's hard to find an *authoritative* single source of documentation for CSS3. [CSS2.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) was easy to find. It was one monolithic easy to read spec even when it was a draft. [However](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/#intro):

> for CSS beyond Level 2, the CSS Working Group chose to adopt a modular approach, where each module defines a part of CSS, rather than to define a single monolithic specification. This breaks the specification into more manageable chunks and allows more immediate, incremental improvement to CSS.

That does not mean there can't be a monolithic view of the modules and how they fit together. I don't think they really value that in the CSS3 WG right now for some reason. This has been asked on the CSS3 mailing list last year, this the [reply](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Jan/0436.html):

> ... years ago, there was probably still some feeling that we
>   would produce an omnibus CSS3 spec similar to the 2.1 spec, but that
>   feeling died a long time ago.  (If we ever do produce such a thing,
>   it'll be automated.)
>
> You can see all of our specs at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/, though,
>   which is *similar* to having an omnibus document with a
>   not-very-useful title page!

They also do these [snapshots](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/) summaries of all CSS work to date, which aren't very useful or readable.